# How can we prove Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem by using Heine -Borel theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

How  can  we  prove  Bolzano - Weierstrass  theorem  which  says,  "In  $\Bbb R$ , every  bounded, infinite subset  has  at  least   one  limit  point (in $\Bbb R$) "  by  using  Heine- Borel  theorem (In  $\Bbb R$, every open cover of a closed  and  bounded  subset has a finite subcover)

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is bounded and infinie subset of $R$ , it is obviously in a closed and bounded set like $B$ so by the $Heine-Borel \ \ theorem$ every open cover of $B$ has a finite subcover. suppose that $A$ does not have any limit point at $B$ so every point of $A$ like $t$ is contained in a open ball that it's intersection with $B$ is only ${t}$ . now these open balls create a open covering for $B$ that has finite subcover. now $A$ is contained in the union of finite balls that every ball has only one element of $A$ so $A$ must be finite set and it is contradiction.

Comment: Good  proof  Masoud  thanks